# How can I successfully cull a list of lists

Tags: python, list, set

So I'm running a script that's appending to a list, lists of values, but in several instances I'll end up with virtually the same data, it'll just be re-ordered differently, I want to put in a check against this by checking my appended list to see if my re-ordered list is essentially there.  For instance, I'll have a list like this:

```
sampleList = [
    [0,5,1,4,8,9],
    [5, 4, 8, 9, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 4, 5, 8, 9],
    [4, 8, 1, 0, 5, 9],
    [7,6,2],
]
```

I essentially want to either remove "duplicates" (which can have another order of the same elements) from this list or append just the first and non-duplicate results and ditch the rest to end up with a list like this:

```
culledList = [
    [0,5,1,4,8,9],
    [7,6,2],
]
```

Comment: I can't edit for formatting since it requires substantial changes (6 characters). Could you remove the initial indentation, and use two newlines instead of one for the line breaks?

Comment: what language are you using? Please add the tag for that language

Comment: the order of element in the list matter? the list can have multiples of the same element?

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with discarding duplicates, you can actually create sets, cause they're easy:

```
sample_list = [
    [0,5,1,4,8,9],
    [5, 4, 8, 9, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 4, 5, 8, 9],
    [4, 8, 1, 0, 5, 9],
    [7,6,2],
]

# This is a set comprehension. Unfortunately,
# sets are not hashable, so we have to convert
# to a `tuple`, which is.
culled_data = {tuple(set(sublist)) for sublist in sample_list}

# or as @Copperfield so helpfully pointed out, a frozenset
culled_data = {frozenset(sublist) for sublist in sample_list}

print(culled_data)
print(list(culled_data))

# Here is a list comprehension to produce a list of
# lists kind of like our original format. If that
# is important, anyway.
culled_list = [list(data) for data in culled_data]
print(culled_list)
```

Comment: you can use `frozenset` instead, is a hashable and inmutable set

Answer (score 0):

If the order inside the sampleList's lists doesn't matter you can sort ALL the lists before appending them with the .sort() method. This would uncover duplicates and provide a check possibility.

```
    sampleList=[[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]]
    l=[2,3,1]
    if not(l.sort() in sampleList): sampleList.append(l.sort())
```

This would not add l to sampleList, because l.sort (which is [1,2,3]) sampleList already contains an identical element.

---

EDIT

```
    culledList=[]
    sortedList=[]
    for i in sampleList:
        if not(i.sort() in sortedList):
            sortedList.append(i.sort())
            culledList.append(i)
```

Comment: What if the sample list was this though?
[[1,2,3,4], [2,1,3,4],[4,3,2,1],[7,6,2,1] ] 
I'd still want the end list to look like this;
[[1,2,3,4],[7,6,2,1]]